# controlling the value (TRUE or FALSE) of dummy variables in interaction terms when using lm()

Tags: r

When I estimate a model that has an interaction between two variables that don't enter the model as standalone variables, and when one of these variables is a dummy (class "logical") variable, R "flips the sign" of the dummy variable.  That is, it reports an estimate of the coefficient on the interaction term when the dummy is FALSE, not when it is TRUE.  Here is an example:

```
data(trees)
trees$dHeight <- trees$Height > 76
trees$cGirth  <- trees$Girth - mean(trees$Girth)
lm(Volume ~ Girth +  Girth:dHeight, data = trees)  # estimate is for  Girth:dHeightTRUE
lm(Volume ~ Girth + cGirth:dHeight, data = trees)  # estimate is for cGirth:dHeightFALSE
```

Why does the regression in the last line produce an estimate for an interaction in which `dHeight` is FALSE rather than TRUE?  (I would like R to report the estimate when dHeight is TRUE.)

This is not a big problem, but I would like to better understand why R is doing what it's doing.  I know about `relevel()` and `contrasts()`, but I can't see that they would make a difference here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dHeight` is `logical`. Within `model` this coerced to a factor, and the levels are sorted lexicographically (i.e. F is before T).

As noted in @Hongooi's answer, you can't estimate 4 parameters, so R will fit the terms in the order they appear (FALSE before TRUE)

If you want to force `R` to fit the `TRUE` value first you could fit the model to `!dHeight`

```
lm(formula = Volume ~ Girth + cGirth:!dHeight, data = trees)
```

Note that `!dHeightFALSE` is equivalent of `dHeightTRUE`

You will also note that  in this simple case you are simply changing the sign on the coefficient so it doesn't really matter which model you fit.

---

EDIT A FAR BETTER APPROACH

R can regcognize that `cGirth` and `Girth` are colinear, therefore we can fit remembering  that `a/b` expands to be `a + a:b`

```
lm(formula = Volume ~ Girth + cGirth/dHeight, data = trees)
Coefficients:
       (Intercept)               Girth              cGirth  cGirth:dHeightTRUE  
           -27.198               4.251                  NA               1.286
```

This provides coefficients with easy to interpret names and `R` will sensibly fail to return a coefficient for `cGirth`

---

`R` can tell `Girth` and `cGirth` are colinear, when they are both the model as "main effect" or standalone terms.

There is no way that `R` should be able to tell when fitting `Girth + cGirth:dHeight` that `cGirth` and `Girth` are colinear and given that `dHeight` is logical we want `cGirthdHeightTRUE` to be the coefficient you fit. (you could write your own formula parser to do this if you really wanted)

another approach that would fit the model you wanted, and without *any* colinear terms would be to use

```
lm(formula = Volume ~ Girth + I(cGirth*dHeight), data = trees)
```

which coerces `dHeight` to numeric (`TRUE becomes 1`).

---

Edit to labor the point.

When you fit `~Girth + Girth:dHeight`

What you are saying is that there is a main effect for `Girth` + adjustments for `dHeight`. R considers the first level of a factor the reference level. The slope for `dHeightFALSE` is simply the value for `Girth`, you then have the adjustment for when `dHeight == TRUE` (Girth:dHeightTRUE).

When you fit `~Girth + cGirth:dHeight` -- `R` does not have a mind-reading parser that can tell that given `cGirth` and `Girth` are co-linear when you fit the interaction of the two terms, it will assume that the second level for `dHeight` is now the reference level)

Imagine if you had a variable that was totally unrelated to `Girth`

eg

```
set.seed(1)
trees$cG <- runif(nrow(trees))
```

Then when you fit `Girth  + cG:dHeight`, you will get 4 parameters estimated

```
lm(formula = Volume ~ Girth + cG:dHeight, data = trees)

Call:
lm(formula = Volume ~ Girth + cG:dHeight, data = trees)

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)            Girth  cG:dHeightFALSE   cG:dHeightTRUE  
      -31.79645          4.79435         -5.92168          0.09578
```

Which is sensible.

When `R` processes `Girth + cGirth:dHeight`, it will expand out (with the first level of the factor first) `1 + Girth + cGirth:dHeightFALSE + cGirth:dHeightTRUE` -- and will work out that it can't estimate all 4 parameters, and will estimate the first 3.

Comment: Thank you. The idea that R is coercing `dHeight` to a factor, and then sorting the levels lexicographically, makes some sense. It would explain why R is reporting an estimate for an interaction in which `dHeight` is FALSE rather than TRUE.  But if that is what is happening, why does R fit an interaction with `dHeightTRUE` in `lm(Volume ~ Girth + Girth:dHeight, data = trees)`? This is the formula in the second-to-last line of my example. The only difference between it and the formula in the last line is that it includes `Girth`, rather than `cGirth`, in the interaction term.

Comment: Thanks again.  I see the edit, and I like the idea.  But I still don't see why R fits an interaction with `dHeightTRUE` in `lm(Volume ~ Girth + Girth:dHeight, data = trees)`.  Do you have any ideas on this point?

Comment: @user697473 Because you told it to.

Answer (score 1):

R isn't flipping the sign on the dummy variable as such. When you fit `~ Girth + cGirth:dHeight`, the `cGirth` variable is confounded with the intercept term. You can see what's going on by removing the intercept:

```
> lm(Volume ~ -1 + Girth + cGirth:dHeight, data = trees)

Call:
lm(formula = Volume ~ -1 + Girth + cGirth:dHeight, data = trees)

Coefficients:
              Girth  cGirth:dHeightFALSE   cGirth:dHeightTRUE  
              2.199                2.053                3.339
```

Comment: Thank you -- I see that.  But how can I get R to estimate a model that includes an intercept and `cGirth:dHeight:TRUE`, but not `cGirth:dHeightFALSE`?  (I can think of inelegant ways to do this, but I would like to know if there is a succinct or standard way.)